# Tesseract OCR распознавание мелких цифр

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

Tesseract OCR не распознаёт мелкие цифры, а именно 6 и 9, другие распознаёт как надо

Исх изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread('src_path...')

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
scale_percent = 400  # percent of original size
width = int(img_gray.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img_gray.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
resized_img = cv2.resize(img_gray, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized_img, (3, 3), 0)
blur_img = cv2.medianBlur(blur_img, 3)

thresh, new_img = cv2.threshold(blur_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU |cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

custom_config = '--psm 12 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
digits = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_img, lang='eng', config=custom_config)
print(digits)
```

После всех преобразований получаем вот такое изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но и это tesseract не распознаёт, что можно сделать?

upd 1: Временное решение, увеличил изображение в 10 раз и применил сильный blur (`medianBlur` значение от 13 до 21)... `tesseract` Стал определять. Но есть ли более правильное решение моей проблемы?

Comment: Попробуйте утончить, скруглить. Но как это сделать не знаю :)

Comment: Алексей, к сожалению, ничего сделать нельзя

Comment: Может просто увеличить изображение?

Comment: @Александр Это как-раз было сделано и судя по коду и судя по второй картинке

Comment: Но так автор и говорит что это помогло)

Comment: Попробуйте лучше на **MLKit** от **Google** (_советую лично_). Вот [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/471542/)  на **habr**

Comment: Есть идея - посмотреть, нельзя ли сразу в тессеракт передатьизображение получше. Я понимаю, что этоо может быть "не под контролем разработчика", но обычно "конвеер" выглядит так: хорошая, с высоким разрешением камера -> сжатие, обычно с уменьшением разрешения -> рааспознавание. Может, можно выкинуть средний этап? потому что камеры сейчас - ого-го! Это можкт быть даже закопано где то в настройках - надо просто сохранить изображение из OpenCV, сохранить его же, полученнео с камеры другим способом, и сравнить у них разрешение

Comment: @S.H. это обрезанный скриншот с экрана

Comment: Алексей, а напишите чуть подробнее - отокуда берется изображение? в том смысле, нельзя ли его получить изначально с лучшим разрешением? И каков источник - камера, сканер, печатный текст, или что то компьютерное?

Comment: @S.H. Это максимальное разрешение и размер шрифта

Comment: Увеличить изображение - самый правильный вариант. Что вам в нем не понравилось? Tesseract натренирован на отсканированный текст, сделайте на вход ему буквы привычного для него размера и все распознает отлично.

Comment: blur кстати не нужен, просто увеличивайте картинку методом [lanczos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling), самое простое - использовать [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)

Comment: @DiD, а чем плох мой метод увеличения изображения? Есть подводные камни?

Comment: @Алексей blur там не нужен, наоборот, лучше подчеркнуть контраст.

Comment: @DiD без blur цифры 1, 2, 5, 6 путает (не верно определяет)

Comment: @Алексей потому что увеличиваете не соблюдая метод lanczos

Comment: @Алексей Сравните размытие гауса с lanczos [здесь](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.hires.png)

Comment: @DiD. хотелось бы увидеть полноценный ответ: как, что, где увеличивать

Answer (score 3):

Исходным изображением взял:
[image]

Инвертируйте цвета, тк тессеракт лучше воспринимает черный шрифт на белом фоне и поставьте psm 8

Возможные варианты psm:

- 0 = Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
- 1 = Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
- 2 = Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR. (not implemented)
- 3 = Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
- 4 = Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
- 5 = Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
- 6 = Assume a single uniform block of text.
- 7 = Treat the image as a single text line.
- 8 = Treat the image as a single word.
- 9 = Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
- 10 = Treat the image as a single character.
- 11 = Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
- 12 = Sparse text with OSD.
- 13 = Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
  bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.

oem:

- 0 = Original Tesseract only.
- 1 = Neural nets LSTM only.
- 2 = Tesseract + LSTM.
- 3 = Default, based on what is available.

Описания режимов взяты [отсюда](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/main/doc/tesseract.1.asc)

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('ZZt0xKV.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
scale_percent = 400  # percent of original size
width = int(img_gray.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img_gray.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
resized_img = cv2.resize(img_gray, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized_img, (3, 3), 0)
blur_img = cv2.medianBlur(blur_img, 3)

thresh, new_img = cv2.threshold(blur_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU |cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

new_img = cv2.bitwise_not(new_img)

custom_config = '--psm 8 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
digits = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_img, lang='eng', config=custom_config)
print(digits.strip()) # 9
```

Полезная [ссылка](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) с советами по повышению качества распознавания

upd: взял код преобразования из вопроса, изменил параметры psm

Comment: А что выводит `print` добавьте в ответ.

Comment: Было бы не плохо рассказать за что отвечают параметры psm 10 и oem 1.

Comment: @RayVik, ответ, толком не помог. Если использовать другое изображение (с такой же цифрой 9), не определит её. Вот например: https://i.imgur.com/ZZt0xKV.png

Comment: @Алексей обновил ответ